# ggplot facet_wrap: At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Tags: facet-wrap

I am using the command

```
qplot(factor(ww), WeeklyYield, geom = "bar", fill = I("grey50"))+facet_wrap(~model+name)
```

to create a bar chart for every combination of `model` and `name`. However I get the following error message:

> Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
>     At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

I cannot uncode this message.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if it still helps after so much time, but I suspect the problem is that you're feeding a formula into `facet_wrap()`, whereas it can only take a variable, e.g. `facet_wrap(~model)`.

If you want a formula, try `facet_grid()` as an alternative, e.g. `facet_grid(.~model+name)`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like ggplot does not found 'model' and /or 'name' column in your dataframe WeeklyYield.
You should check with `names(WeeklyYield)`